# Reading UID of mifare classic 1k

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

In the simplest form, are there any examples, or code snippets showing how I can read the UID of a mifare card on my android phone?

I do not need to read/write anything in any of the sectors, I just need the 4 or 7 byte UID

I tried googling but didn't really come across anything concrete

Answer (score 1):

use command **FF CA 00 00 00** for get UID from mifare 1k card.

Comment: This works, but where is such commands documented?